# MIPS program that prints 2^x (x is user-input value)

Tags: assembly, mips

Essentially, I need to have the user input some value x, perform this operation:

> 2^x

and then print out whatever value that is. I'm not sure what's the best way to tackle this. Should I just do loop multiplication (like multiply 2 * 2 x times) or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Think how binary works and what doubling a value in binary does.

Comment: Maybe do some Shifting with bits (SLL)

Answer (score 0):

Since Binary to decimal goes by powers of 2's... assuming you don't exceed the maximum space in the register... you can use the Shift Left Logical Command to push a bit from the 1's to the 2's slot... etc.